# Can Struts 2 run on Apache2 server without Tomcat?

Tags: apache, struts2

Please help! I got very frustrated with this assignment to demonstrate Apache and Java Struts. I cannot make struts apps run in the Apache web directory. They only work under Tomcat.

Can I use Struts only under Apache without Tomcat? ... Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache and Tomcat serve different purposes. You cannot use Apache to run Struts because it's just a web server, not a java web container.

What you could do is to setup Apache as a reverse proxy to a tomcat instance, so the "Internet" would talk to your Apache, but still Tomcat would be serving your requests in the end.

Comment: @jess if this resolved your issue please marked solution as solved.